# how to mock windows authenticated role for integration test - web api 2

Tags: unit-testing, windows-authentication, asp.net-web-api2

I am doing integration tests on our web api 2 app which distinguish people on their principle roles and grant different level of access accordingly. Since they are integration tests, I only want to create a HttpClient, pass a parameter and make an api call. And of course, mock people with different roles.

Now I am using the code like:

```
 [Test]
    public async void  Get_ShouldGetAccount_WhenValid()
    {
        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            UseDefaultCredentials = true
        };
        using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://example.com");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));       
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/accounts/123456");

            Assert.IsTrue(response.IsSuccessStatusCode);

        }
    }
```

and it works with my own windows account.

I'm pretty new to this, so could someone point me to the right direction please? A more detailed explanation will be greatly appreciated. I use NUnit.

Thanks for taking your time to read this.

Comment: Not clear on what you are asking for.